# How to calculate the double integral Numerically in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-computing

How to calculate the double integral Numerically in Mathematica ?

```
Integrate[Exp[-0.099308 s]
       * Integrate[Exp[0.041657423 u] Exp[-3.1413 s + 3.12 u]
             * ((u/(s - u))^(1/2) BesselI[1,2 (u (s - u))^(1/2)]
             + 0.293 BesselI[0,2 (u (s - u))^(1/2)]),{u,0,s}],{s,0,10}]
```

[image]

Comment: possible (near) duplicate of [How to calculate the double integral Numerically in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554617/how-to-calculate-the-double-integral-numerically-in-matlab)

Comment: How could a Mathematica question be a dupe of a Matlab question? That would be like a Java question and a C# question.

Comment: @Verbeia you have a point, yet the OP asked how to approach the same integral in both languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things. First of all, [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integrate.html) accepts multiple "iterators", i.e. `{x, x1, x2}`, so you can specify a multiple integral without nesting them, as follows

```
Integrate[x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}]
```

integrates `x y` over the triangle bounded by `y == x`, `x == 0`, and `x == 1`. Note, the order of the limits, they go from outer to inner, so the integration is performed from right to left.  Then, your integral becomes

```
Integrate[Exp[-0.099308 s] Exp[0.041657423 u] Exp[-3.1413 s + 3.12 u]
   * ((u/(s - u))^(1/2) BesselI[1,2 (u (s - u))^(1/2)]
   + 0.293 BesselI[0,2 (u (s - u))^(1/2)]),
 {s,0,10}, {u,0,s}]
```

Second, Mathematica has a number of numerical equivalents to its standard algorithms, like [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html), [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html), [`NSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSum.html), and [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NIntegrate.html). They are all identifiable by the leading `N`, which is a [function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html) in its own right, too. The nice thing about these functions is that they have the same signature as their analytical equivalent. So, to numerically integrate your integral, you simply change `Integrate` to `NIntegrate`, as follows

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-0.099308 s] Exp[0.041657423 u] Exp[-3.1413 s + 3.12 u]
   * ((u/(s - u))^(1/2) BesselI[1,2 (u (s - u))^(1/2)]
   + 0.293 BesselI[0,2 (u (s - u))^(1/2)]),
 {s,0,10}, {u,0,s}]
```

which gives `27.4182`, as noted by [tkott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9585980/198315), but without any warnings generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to numerically integrate something in Mathematica, you should use NIntegrate instead. This will give you a numerical approximation rather than the definite integral.

```
NIntegrate[ Exp[-0.099308*s]*
  NIntegrate[Exp[0.041657423*u]*(Exp[-3.1413*s + 3.12*u])*((u/(s - u))^(1/2)*
       BesselI[1, 2*(u*(s - u))^(1/2)] + 0.293*BesselI[0, 2*(u*(s - u))^(1/2)])
  , {u, 0, s}]
, {s, 0, 10}]
```

It complains because the inner integrate is evaluated first, and cannot be evaluated without specifying `s`, but gives

```
27.4182
```

No idea if this is correct or not!

BTW: you might get a better response over at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/